# How to install R statistics system and r-cran-tidyverse in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, ppa, repository, r

I am trying to set up a new Ubuntu 20.04 server (to replace an older 18.04 server) which needs to have the `R` statistics system and, in particular, the `r-cran-tidyverse` package installed.

I am using the CRAN repository as it seems to be recommended, for R packages, in preference to Ubuntu's own repository, as the CRAN repo has more packages available.

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

I have added the repo:

```
echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/" \
 | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-cran40.list
```

and imported its security key

```
# apt-key may fail because of firewall restrictions, so try
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
#
# Do not forget the trailing dash!
gpg -a --export E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then installed the base packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

So far, so good.

My notes for Ubuntu 18.04 said, to add `marutter`'s repo for additional R packages, to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-cran-tidyverse
```

It looks as though (from the CRAN page linked above) that the `marutter` repos (or another additional R repos) have changed since then.

Is it now the [cran2deb4ubuntu 4.0 (c2d4u4.0+)](https://launchpad.net/~c2d4u.team/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u4.0+) repo that I need to use instead to install `r-cran-tidyverse` (following the instructions on that repo's page)?

Answer (score 2):

r-base and r-cran-tidyverse are provided by the default repositories in Ubuntu 20.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base r-cran-tidyverse
```